# Including dependencies in Ansible + Test Kitchen

Tags: ansible, test-kitchen

I am trying to get Ansible + Test Kitchen to work and my code is available at [Github](https://github.com/alexharv074/ansible-nexus).

When running `kitchen test` it errors out with:

```
   ERROR! the role 'geerlingguy.java' was not found in /tmp/kitchen/roles:/tmp/kitchen:/tmp/kitchen/roles:/tmp/kitchen/roles

   The error appears to have been in '/tmp/kitchen/roles/ansible-nexus/meta/main.yml': line 3, column 5, but may
   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

   The offending line appears to be:

   dependencies:
     - { role: geerlingguy.java }
```

Is there a way to tell Test Kitchen to firstly pull in dependencies from Ansible Galaxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include following changes:
.kitchen.yml

```
provisioner:
  hosts: test-kitchen
  name: ansible_playbook
  #require_chef_for_busser: false
  #require_ruby_for_busser: true
  ansible_verbosity: 2
  ansible_verbose: true
  require_ansible_repo: false
  require_ansible_omnibus: true
  requirements_path: requirements-test.txt
  #
  # When testing with Test Kitchen, run the Docker client with
  # "--insecure-registry registry.yourdomain.local" so that we can test pushing
  # to our test private registry.
  #
  #extra_vars:
  #  docker_opts: "--insecure-registry registry.yourdomain.local"
```

requirements-test.txt

```
geerlingguy.java
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way of doing this: create an `Ansiblefile` based on doco [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/librarian-ansible/2.0.0), add `gem 'librarian-ansible'` to `Gemfile`, and specify the the role in `test/integration/default/default.yml`.  I suspect, however, that @Valeriy Solovyov's answer is more correct.